# XKB - remap arrow keys and preserve shift behaviour to select text

Tags: remapping, xkb, shift

I realize arrow key remapping is an old problem, however I cannot seem to find a good solution that lets me select text with SHIFT + remapped keys as I would do with the vanilla arrow keys.

For instance, if I remap Caps Lock to ISO_Level3_Shift and set xkb_symbols to read either

```
key <AC08>  { [         k,          K , Down, Down] };
```

or

```
key <AC08>  { type="THREE_LEVEL",
              [         k,          K , Down ]  };
```

Pressing Shift+CapsLock+K will behave exactly as CapsLock+K (while Shift+Down behaves differently from Down alone).

I had somewhat more success using higher level macro utilities and generating keyboard events (i.e. generate both the shift and the arrow keypresses); hoever that approach has a whole set of different problems - often the UI response to a simulated keypress is different from the "real" keypress, and there are performance problems as well - I can type faster than the thing can handle.

Tl;dr; how can you shift-select using remapped arrow keys under X?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `preserve` for that: add to you type-definition (e.g. `THREE_LEVEL`) the line

```
preserve[LevelThree+Shift] = Shift;
```

This tells xkb to preserve the shift modifier when figuring out the appropriate level from your modifier combination in the case of `LevelThree + Shift`. The shift modifier is passed on for use by the toolkit or the application (see also here: [using preserve with types](http://pascal.tsu.ru/en/xkb/gram-types.html#preserve)).

Note that this has impact for example on how the application interprets keystroke combinations: if you had defined the above preserve and

```
key <AC08> { type="THREE_LEVEL", [ k, K, kappa ]  };
```

and you'd press `Ctrl + Shift + LevelThree + <AC08>` the application would read it as a key combo `Ctrl + Shift + kappa` (instead of usually `Ctrl + kappa`)  because the shift modifier gets preserved and is passed on to the application.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I'm missing one final piece: is it possible to configure xkb so that one keystroke toggles the shift (or other) keys? What I want to do is is having for example CapsLock+s  toggle the shift key, so that I can use Capkslock+jkl to select text.